# Multiple artifacts of the module in Ivy

Tags: build, ivy

I would like to retrieve jar to a specific folder(like lib) by ivy, below is my retrieve definition in the build.xml:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact].[ext]" conf="webInfLib" />
```

And the definition of my ivy.xml like below:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
       xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="xxxx" module="xxxx" status="integration"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="webInfLib"  description="add jar to web-inf/lib folder"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-beans" rev="2.5.5" transitive="false" conf="webInfLib -> default"/>
        <dependency org="net.sf.json-lib" name="json-lib" rev="2.3"> 
            <artifact name="json-lib" type="jar" m:classifier="jdk15"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

But it always throws:

```
impossible to ivy retrieve: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple artifacts of the module xxxxxx are retrieved to the same file! Update the retrieve pattern  to fix this error.
```

I have read some similar question and their suggest to change the retrieve pattern to a more complex one. I try something like "[artifact]-revision.[ext]", but not help. And when I execute "ivy.resolve", it work fines. Is there any suggestion about this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The retrieve pattern is the problem that's true.
You are trying

```
[artifact]-[revision].ext
```

so I would imagine the binary jar and the source jar would be both written on the same location for any arbitrary dependency. But if you add something unique to the case that you are having

```
[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

In the case of a source or doc, the classifier would have a value and therefore would have a different name. In case of no classifier (like the case of the binary compiled jar) there won't be any classifier and this is dealt with by the parentheses ( )

Comment: Thanks for your reply.your analysis is correct but the solution not help(I have try your suggestion earlier).Finally, I added 'type="jar"' to retrieve tag and it work. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Getting things done, that's the important thing.
But as a last follow up since the type is the one causing the problem, You could add the type to the pattern as well: [type]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext].
which will bring your jar along other types or artifacts

Comment: @EyadEbrahim Be careful with folder in patter. If you add sync="true", this pattern remove all folder where is build.xml
I think that pattern must by "${lib.path}/[type]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"